# how can i show icon to expand details table only when details table is not empty

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, master-detail

I'm using ag-grid enterprise.

I'm using master details with javascript ,
like in this example:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#

i want to use a json string that have only a few child table.

how can i disable the expand icon when details table is empty and show the expand icon only when details have at least one row.

for example i use this json

```
[{
    "name": "Nora Thomas",
    "account": 177000,
    "calls": 24,
    "minutes": 25.65,
    "callRecords": [{
        "name": "susan",
        "callId": 555,
        "duration": 72,
        "switchCode": "SW3",
        "direction": "Out",
        "number": "(00) 88542069"
    }, {
        "name": "susan",
        "callId": 556,
        "duration": 61,
        "switchCode": "SW3",
        "direction": "In",
        "number": "(01) 7432576"
    }] },
    {
        "name": "Mila Smith",
        "account": 177001,
        "calls": 24,
        "minutes": 26.216666666666665} ]
```

for "Nora Thomas" i want to be able to open and show the details table,

for "Mila Smith" i dont want to show the icon that expand the details table.

thanks.

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.